# caching clearing

Tags: spring-mvc, browser-cache

I have to implement cache clearing (like when we refresh form is not submitted again) in my application, where using spring MVC.

Is there any inbuilt filter available or any other way to customize a filter for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the user re-posting you might want to redirect to your view rather than simply returning it.

From the spring documentation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting